# How do I secure my custom Magento2 REST api

Tags: rest, security, magento2

I created a custom REST api in Magento2. But, how do I secure it with the built-in Magento2 REST api security?

just like /index.php/rest/V1/customers/me is secured with the Authorization header

Answer (score 2):

while creating custom api configuration in **webapi.xml** put `ref="self"`

if you configured like this you can access API with authentication only provided by magento 2 like oauth,token,oauth2

Disable access for api to anonymous in admin panel of magento

Comment: Also you can use customerId to achieve customer's specific behaviour. Have a look at webapi.xml file in Magento/Customer to see how they do it.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `<resource ref="anonymous"/>` by `<resource ref="Venodr_Module::name_of_the_acl_entry"/>` in the `etc/webapi.xml` of your module:

```
<route url="/V1/customers/me" method="...">
    <service class="..." method="..."/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Vendor_Module::name_of_the_acl_entry"/>
        <!--<resource ref="anonymous"/>-->
    </resources>
</route>
```

and setup ACL in the `etc/acl.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Vendor_Module::name_of_the_acl_entry" title="Human readable title"/>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Then grant access for concrete backend user in "*System / Permissions / User Roles*", select *Role*, tab "*Role Resources*" and "*Resource Access*". Select "*All*" or select "*Custom*" and check resource named "Human readable title".

Answer (score 2):

Access Security on Custom api applied through

Magento 2 allows some web APIs to be accessed by unauthenticated (anonymous) users.To prevent access to anonymous user , define a resource to which the caller must have access. Like ,

```
<route url="/V1/techyrules/webservice/deleteAddressMine" method="PUT">
    <service class="techyrules\WebService\Api\AddressManagementInterface" method="deleteAddressMine"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self"/>
        </resources>
</route>
```

ref, Valid values are self, anonymous, or a Magento resource, such as Magento_Customer::group.

**Self** example,
user authenticate him/herself by username & password then token will be generated in response that token act as self permission for further processes.